# Order of incoming actions in actionchannel differs

Tags: redux-saga

I have a react native app, where I need to simply persist all the raw actions dispatched in the app. The idea is that I get a simple kind of event-store which I, at a later point, can aggregate reports and statistics on.
A requirement is that every action is persisted *as is*, and that they are persisted *in the order they where dispatched*.

I went with the simply case of using the `actionChannel` effect:

```
import { actionChannel, call, take } from 'redux-saga/effects'

export function* track() {
  const catchAll = yield actionChannel('*');
  while (true) {
    const action = yield take(catchAll);
    yield call(persist, action);
  }
}
```

This persists all actions, but not in the order they where dispatched. However, using the Redux DevTools, I see the right order being reported.

Is there anything obvious that I have missed here?
How can I be guaranteed to get the right order?
Does `actionChannel()` even work like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that it was very simple: The `track` saga was the last one to get registred. After moving `sagaMiddleware.run(track);` to be the first one, things worked as expected.

However, the order of any actions besides the first ones would properly have been in the right order anyway. But I was focussed on the first ~5 actions *not* being in the right order.